# Integration of simple functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ and $g$ be two simple functions such that $f \leq g$ defined over some measure space $(\Omega, \sigma, \mu)$. Is is true that $\int_\Omega f \leq \int_{\Omega} g$?

It seems to be true so I tried to write $f = \sum \alpha_k 1_{A_k}$ and $g = \sum \beta_k 1_{B_k}$, but how can I make the indicator functions be defined over the same set?

Comment: Consider the family of intersections $A_k\cap B_j$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just take the pairwise intersections of the sets where f is single -valued and those where g is single -valued and on each of these sets f$\leq$g and the integrals of the two is just the sum of the values times measures of these sets. Since each of these sets have the same measure you're done.